# Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: MediatR.IRequestHandler

Tags: cqrs, clean-architecture, mediatr, asp.net-core-6.0, c#-10.0

I implement **JwtService** from **IJwtService** at the **Infrastructure layer**
**IJwtService** declare at the **Application layer**
and

I implement **IdentityService** from **IIdentityService** at the **Infrastructure** layer

I register both at **infrastructure dependency injection** like

```
services.AddTransient< IJwtService,JwtService>();
services.AddTransient<IIdentityService,IdentityService>();
```

Then I implement LoginQueryHandler implement from : IRequestHandler<LoginViewModel, LoginDto>
within LoginQueryHandler() i inject IIdentityService and IJwtService

I register Mediator at Application Layer as this

```
services.AddMediatR(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

using mediator I send a request to LoginQuery Handler

```
public async Task Login([FromBody] LoginViewModel model)
{

        return await Mediator.Send(model);
}
```

This is LoginQueryHandler Class

```
public class LoginViewModel: IRequest<LoginDto>
{
public string Email { get; set; }
public string Password { get; set; }


}
public class LoginQueryHandler : IRequestHandler<LoginViewModel, LoginDto>
{

private readonly IIdentityService _identityService;
private readonly IJwtService _jwtService;
public LoginQueryHandler(IIdentityService identityService,IJwtService jwtService)
{
    _identityService=identityService;
    _jwtService=jwtService;
    
}

public async Task<LoginDto> Handle(LoginViewModel request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        var user = await _identityService.FindByEmailAsync(request.Email);
       // codes....
        return new LoginDto();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
   
}
}
```

but it throws the following error

System.InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[Application.Login.Queries.LoginViewModel,Application.Login.Queries.LoginDto] Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: Application.Login.Queries.LoginQueryHandler': Unable to resolve service for type 'TechneTravel.Infrastructure.Services.JwtService' while attempting to activate 'Newproject.Infrastructure.Identity.IdentityService'.
---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Newproject.Infrastructure.Services.JwtService' while attempting to activate 'Newproject.Infrastructure.Identity.IdentityService'

Then I tried three ways to register Request Handler at the Application layer as bellow

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IRequestHandler<LoginViewModel, LoginDto>), typeof(LoginQueryHandler));

 services.AddTransient<IRequestHandler<LoginViewModel, LoginDto>, LoginQueryHandler>();
 services.AddTransient(typeof(LoginQueryHandler));
```

but not solved

Comment: @Guru Stron  could you see this issue

Comment: @GuruStron This solved the problem
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your error message it seems that you are trying to resolve `JwtService` in your `Newproject.Infrastructure.Identity.IdentityService` but you have only interface registration:

```cs
services.AddTransient<IJwtService, JwtService>();
```

So either change your `IdentityService` to accept `IJwtService` instead of `JwtService` (I would say that it is far better option) or change/add registration to inject using concrete class:

```cs
services.AddTransient<JwtService>();
```

Comment: could you see this question as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70548930/failed-to-load-snap-dotnet-sdk-152-shared-microsoft-netcore-app-6-0-1-libcorecl#

Comment: @AbdulganyMohamed have no idea what is the problem there. Can only suggest trying to install [without snap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu).