# Failed to load /snap/dotnet-sdk/152/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.1/libcoreclr.so Error

Tags: .net-6.0, ef-core-6.0

Previously I installed the .Net Core 3.1.416 version and `dotnet-ef` 3.1.416 version.

I used

`dotnet-ef migrations add Test  -p <path to domain layer> -s <path to solution file> --context  ApplicationDbContext`

command to add a database migration

then I  have to install the .Net core 6.0.101 version SDK for a new project. Then I upgrade  `dotnet-ef` 6.0.101 version.

Then I add migration at the .Net 6.0 project or 3.1.416 it throws the following error

```
Failed to load /snap/dotnet-sdk/152/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.1/libcoreclr.so, error: /snap/dotnet-sdk/152/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/6.0.1/../../../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1: undefined symbol: __clock_nanosleep, version GLIBC_PRIVATE
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

when I run `dotnet --list-sdks` command it shows the below output

```
3.1.416 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
6.0.101 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
```

Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Hi , Did you upgrade in a linux environment?

Answer (score 0):

I installed Dotnet SDK 6.0 and 3.1 using the following link

[Install multiple Dotnet versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu#install-the-sdk)

and I use **global.json** file to switch the sdks